# How can I get textbox value based on Id in another table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, textbox

Why doesn't the textbox Name get value by Id?

So this is view ex_op:

[image]

This Id and Name, I get based on tbl_operator. When I entered Id then the Name will show.

This is controller ex_op:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var ex_op = db.ex_op.Include(e => e.tbl_exercises).Include(e => e.tbl_operator);
    return View(ex_op.ToList());
}
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ex_op exop = new ex_op();

    var lasttest = db.ex_op.OrderBy(c => c.idTest).FirstOrDefault();
    if (lasttest == null)
    {
        exop.idTest = "EXOP000";
    }
    else
    {
        exop.idTest = "EXOP" + (Convert.ToInt32(lasttest.idTest.Substring(6, lasttest.idTest.Length - 6)) + 1).ToString("D3");
    }

    ViewBag.idEx = new SelectList(db.tbl_exercises, "idEx","idEx");
    ViewBag.idOp = new SelectList(db.tbl_operator, "idOp","idOp");
    
    return View(exop);
}
```

And this is View ex_op

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Name</label>
    <div class="control-label col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tbl_operator.nama, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tbl_operator.nama, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what I forget in this code, maybe i missing the code
please help me.

Comment: "When I entered Id then the Name will show" - so when the User enters the `ID Operator` you want the `Name` filed to populate automatically? This would normally be done client side with jQuery/Ajax.

Comment: yes, sir. I want automatically field name, so when i choose Id in dropdownlist the `Name` will show automatically in the textbox @LeeStevens

Comment: i already create the Class ListOp @LeeStevens

Answer (score 1):

To auto fill the `Name` field once a `ID Operator` is selected you will need to use events to trigger a call to your Controller and return JSON then fill in the Field.

**Client Side:**
Checks for a change to the operator id dropdown and send a request to the server.

```
$('#OperatorId').change(function() {
    var str = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

    $.ajax('@Url.Action("GetOperatorName", "Home")', {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data : {'operatorId': str }.
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
            if ("success" === status) {
                document.getElementById('#OperatorName').value = data.OperatorName;
            } else {
                alert('This Operator ID is not valid. Try again!');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Server-side:**
Receives the ajax request looks up the operator and return the object

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetOperatorName(string operatorId)
{
    var item = await Operators.Get(x => x.Id == operatorId);
    return Json(item);
}
```

You will need to change the fields and endpoint etc as needed, but this gives you the idea how to achieve what you need.

Comment: so, what  i used  of the view? @LeeStevens